# Live transcription with Twilio Media Streams, Azure Cognitive Services and nodeJS and Angular

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

I'm looking for snippet of code for Live transcription with Twilio Media Streams, Azure Cognitive Services and nodeJS and Angular